# Align Inline Element to the Right

Tags: css

How to align two text elements, one to the left and the other to the right, also on the same line. I'm aware it can be done using floats but I would like a float less solution. I'm looking for a way to do it using `display:inline`.

HTML:

```
<div class="contailner">
    <div class="inlineLeft">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inlineRight">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inlineLeft, .inlineRight {
    display: inline;
}

.inlineRight {
    ...align right...   
}
```

Comment: You'd need `inline-block` and then you could just try adjusting the margins

Answer (score 16):

you could just use `position:absolute` on the inline elements and `position:relative` on the container. Then you can align the inline elements the way you want relative to the container. Something like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inlineLeft, .inlineRight {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

.inlineRight {
    right: 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bYxUC/1/)

Comment: Take a closer look at your demo and you will see that the container's `height` is 0, which is certainly all kinds of wrong. The container's height should *contain* its elements.

Answer (score 12):

## UPDATE - `2019, April`

We can also work with `css flex`.

```css
div.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 2px deeppink dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
    <span>span element 1</span>
    <span>span element 2</span>
</div>
```

---

## PREVIOUS ANSWER

### We can achieve this with `display:table`:

```css
.container {
    border: 2px blue dashed;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    /*MARGIN (NOT REQUIRED)*/
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}
.inlineRight {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
}
.inlineLeft {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inlineLeft">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inlineRight">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 3):

You could use text-align:justify + after pseudo element to justify that first line:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeAgk

```css
.contailner {
  line-height:0;
  text-align:justify;
  background:lightgray;
  margin:1em;
}
.contailner > * {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:1.2em;
}
.contailner:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:99%;
  vertical-align:top;/* or bottom to swallow last gaps */
}

/* some extra possibilities */
ul {padding:0;margin:0;}
.w3 {padding-left:1%;}
.w3 .box {margin:1% 1% 1% 0; border:solid;width:31%;text-align:center;box-shadow:0 0 5px;}
.w3 .w5 {width:48%;}
.w3 .w15 {width:14%;}
.w3 .w25 {width:23%;}
```

```html
<div class="contailner">
    <div class="inlineLeft">Item 1</div>
    <div class="inlineRight">Item 2</div>
</div>
<div class="contailner">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
</div>
<ul class="contailner">
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="contailner w3">
    <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
    <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contailner w3">
    <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
    <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box w5">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box w5">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
      <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w5">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w15">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w25">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w25">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w25">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
        <div class="box w25">
      <header>header</header>
      <article>Article</article>
      <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.contailner {
  line-height:0;
  text-align:justify;
}
.contailner > div {
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:1.2em;
}
.contailner:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

If you use an extra empty element instead of pseudo-element, then you have a technic that is usable since text-align:justify exists, wich means compatible with any browsers.

---

#### Edit 2020

For simple inline elements , nowdays , `text-align-last` works with every browsers. , the pseudo element can be dropped.

```css
.contailner {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 1em;
}

.contailner>* {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* some extra possibilities */

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.w3 {
  padding-left: 1%;
}

.w3 .box {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 0;
  border: solid;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}

.w3 .w5 {
  width: 48%;
}

.w3 .w15 {
  width: 14%;
}

.w3 .w25 {
  width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contailner">
  <div class="inlineLeft">Item 1</div>
  <div class="inlineRight">Item 2</div>
</div>
<div class="contailner">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
</div>
<ul class="contailner">
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link item</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="contailner w3">
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contailner w3">
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w5">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w5">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w5">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w15">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w25">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w25">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w25">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box w25">
    <header>header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

also, nowdays

- there is `flex` and `space-between`  to easily do the job and to use if it is to build a grid layout.
- `text-align`/`text-align-last` should be used only for its original purpose : text alignment,  *not a workaround to something else*.

So what would you choose for a nav ?

```css
.txt {
  text-align-last: justify
}
/* or ? */
.flx {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav class="txt">
  <a href="">Link</a> <a href="">Link</a> <a href="">Link</a>
</nav>
<nav class="flx">
  <a href="">Link</a> <a href="">Link</a> <a href="">Link</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: flexible, this technic allow you to easily build a grid system as well.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your css

```
.inlineLeft, .inlineRight {
    display: inline-block;
}

.inlineRight {
   display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin-right:8px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/J64vr/)

Comment: That gets me in the right direction. If I add position:relative to the container element, inlineRight is aligned right within the container element which is what I want. But if I add padding:8px to the container there is no right padding on the inlineRight element. Do you have a fix without changing right:0. May be anothe example which keep inlineRight in flow. Using position:absolute takes the element out of flow.

Comment: add margin-right:8px in .inlineLeft, .inlineRight you can see in updated demo

Comment: Looks pretty good but I'm having a bit of an issue. Can you help me out here? Why is there this arbitrary 4.182px gap below the images in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J64vr/2/), even though it is not backed by any of the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing it like this?

You can easily have the same result with an un-ordered list without those extra divs.

Make sure you set the text-align property for the first list item to "left" (ul li:first-child), and set the text-align property for the other list items (ul li) to "right".

**UPDATE - Here's the code for this as requested:**

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
padding: 0 0;
margin: 0 0;
list-style: none;
width: 600px;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 30px;
}

ul li{
width: 300px;
display: block;
float: left;
text-align: right;
line-height: 30px;
}

ul li:first-child{
text-align: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wassim_taher/3c976/1/)

Comment: That aligns them to the left and to the right but on two suppurate lines. Do I need to make each li display:inline?

Comment: Yes I forget to mention: please add property "float" equals to "left" on (ul li) css level. Trust me this is the way to do it. You shoudn't be using Divs for this.

Comment: If you're still in doubt let me know and I will create a fiddle for you.

Comment: I think I understand what your telling me to do but it's not working. Please create a fiddle, thank you. Also if one is floating the children shouldn't you float the parent so the parent element doesn't collapses.

Comment: This only works for text. It won't work for arbitrary elements because the height is not set. Is there a way to fix this for non-text element of arbitrary height? [This fiddle illustrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/3c976/36/).

Comment: @Domi Yes you can. under "ul" change the height to "auto" and add another property "float: left;" and it will work. I just tried it starting from your fiddle and it worked. Let me know if you still need help on this.

Comment: @WassimTaher Thanks! `height: auto` is a life-saver. Do you also see a weird margin below the image that does not show up as margin or padding anywhere? [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3c976/38/).